# Real values of $x$ in $(1+2^x)\cdot (1+8^x)\cdot (1+9^x)^2 = (1+6^x)^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $(1)$ Real values of $x$ in $2^x+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+6^x = 4$
>
> $(2)$ Real values of $x$ in $(1+2^x)\cdot (1+8^x)\cdot (1+9^x)^2 = (1+6^x)^4$

**My Try:** For First one:: Here $2^x,3^x,4^{-x},6^{-x}>0$

So Using **A.M** $\geq$ **G.M**

We get $$2^x+\frac{1}{4^x}\geq 2\sqrt{2^{-x}}$$ and $$6^x+\frac{1}{3^x}\geq 2\sqrt{2^{x}}$$

So $$2^x+3^{-x}+4^{-x}+6^x\geq 2\sqrt{2^{-x}}+2\sqrt{2^{x}}\geq 2\cdot 2$$

and equality hold when $$2^{x}=3^{-x}=4^{-x}=6^x$$ and $$\sqrt{2^{x}}=\sqrt{2^{-x}}$$

So we get $x=0$ is only one solution.

$(2)$ Using **Cauchy Schwarz Inequality** Using SchrodingersCat Hint

$\left[1+(\sqrt{2^x})^2\right]\cdot \left[1+\left(\sqrt{8^x}\right)^2\right]\geq (1+2^{2x})^2$

But  I did not understand How can I solve it after that .

Help me Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Think about using **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality**.

For $(1,2^\frac{x}{2})$ and $(1,3^x)$,
by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we can say

$$(1+2^x)(1+9^x)\geq (1+2^\frac{x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2$$

For $(1,2^\frac{3x}{2})$ and $(1,3^x)$,
by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we can say

$$(1+8^x)(1+9^x)\geq (1+2^\frac{3x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2$$

So multiplying the relations, we get $$(1+2^x)(1+8^x)(1+9^x)^2\geq (1+2^\frac{x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2\cdot (1+2^\frac{3x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2$$

Now carefully use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality again on the Right hand side of inequality.

$$(1+2^\frac{x}{2}\cdot 3^x)\cdot (1+2^\frac{3x}{2}\cdot 3^x)\geq (1+6^x)^2$$
$$(1+2^\frac{x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2\cdot (1+2^\frac{3x}{2}\cdot 3^x)^2\geq (1+6^x)^4$$

Hence, we get that 
$$(1+2^x)(1+8^x)(1+9^x)^2\geq (1+6^x)^4$$

The result is for you to make.

Comment: Thanks SchrodingersCat I have used Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality, But how can i solve it after that

Comment: @juantheron I have completed my answer. All the typos have been corrected.